# My.Settings type "string" vs "connection string"

Tags: .net, settings, sql-server-ce, connection-string

What is the difference of these types in My.Settings?  For what do I use "connectionstring"?

What (& why) would I use for a local SQL **Compact** database?

What would I use if I wanted the database location to be chosen/changed in a program options form?

Would it matter if I want a per user setting or not? I don't, I want program to run identical for all Windows user-logins (On the same PC).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the ConnectionString type it is stored in a different section of the config. Not all that different in use but you don't get to choose between Application and User setting (it's forced to Application).

> What (& why) would I use for a local SQL-COMPACT database?
>
> I want program to run identical for all users.

There might be a small conflict here. SQL-CE databases are not suitable for sharing (concurrently) between users.

If you mean "all users on the same PC" there is no problem, use a Connectionstring or a custom Application setting. Only you can't normally change that form the program itself (no Write privileges in ProgramFiles).

Comment: Yes I meant "users on same pc" (edited above). Database is used as storage for single-user desktop winforms program. Sometimes I log in as administrator, sometimes as a user with less privelages, but I just want the program to run identical in both those cases.

Comment: Ah.. I see. Hmm. Actually I always log in as administrator, so wasn't aware i couldn't change the settings as different user. But that's probably good practice, not to allow changing database path unless you are administrator..

Comment: @bretd If you run it as admin you ought to be able to change an App setting, but note that the generated code (Properties namespace) implements them as readonly properties. You'll have to fall back on a the basis API.